# Выборка из двух таблиц

Tags: select, mysql

Не могу сообразить как сделать выбоку такого рода одним запросом:
Есть две таблицы: Табл1 и Табл2. Поля у них разные, но одно поле совпадает(называется также) и это поле email. Мне нужна выборка, которая будет смотреть в эти таблицы и смотреть есть ли поле email с таким значением хотябы в одной из таблиц...

Эту задачу можно решить двумя простыми отдельными запросами SELECT, но как-то жалко делать лишние запросы, как сделать такую выборку одним запросом?

Comment: Лень погуглить? `http://webextends.net/articles/9-mysql/8-mysql-join.html`

Comment: @Palmervan Лень подумать? Скорее всего надо что-то типа

     select email from (select email from tab1 union select email from tab2) a
       where email = 'fool.com'

или лучше

     seleсt * from (select email from tab1 where email = 'fool.com' union
       select email from tab2 where email = 'fool.com') a;

Comment: @Palmervan поскольку из join'ов тут подходит только outer join, который мне не нравится.

Comment: Для тех кто говорит "Лень погуглить или лень подумать"... Вы что блин... думаете, что задавая здесь вопрос я не смотрел в гугле или не думал своей головой? данные запросы не работают... я пробовал, что-то подобное писать ранее и была та же ошибка...  

Every derived table must have its own alias

SELECT * FROM (SELECT `users`.`email` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'мыло' UNION SELECT `invitations`.`email` FROM `invitations` WHERE `invitations`.`email` = 'мыло')

Comment: а выводить ваш запрос что  будет ? сделайте sqlfiddle

Comment: Schema Creation Failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? UNION SELECT `invitations`.`email` FROM `invitations` WHERE `invitations`.`ema' at line 1:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте корректировать согласно Вашим потребностям:

[Пример на SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d4e7/8)

Comment: хммм... у меня первая и вторая таблица разные, там совпадают только поля email... и union не работает вроде бы с разными таблицами...

Comment: Работает, если полям присвоить алиасы так, что бы в результате получилась выборка с одинаковыми полями.

Вот например так: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13089/2

Но если вам это не подходит, правьте под свои требования структуру и содержимое таблиц, будем вместе править запрос.

Answer (score 3):

Итак, у вас две таблицы с разной структурой и разными данными. В каждой из этих таблиц есть поле *email*. Вы хотите сделать так, чтобы при запросе к БД проверились обе таблицы и были выведены данные из той таблицы, где запись с необходимым электронным адресом существует. Если электронный адрес есть в обеих таблицах, тогда (по-видимому) придется объединять данные (если данные из таблицы *invitations* не удаляются при появлении данных в таблице *users*).

Если в таблицах хранятся сильно разные данные, то советую оставить запросы как есть. Вы ведь потом как-то будете эти данные обрабатывать и выводить на экран. Гораздо логичнее в таком случае сделать два запроса, заточенных под конкретные таблицы и работать далее с полученными данными отдельно.

Если очень хочется ограничиться одним запросом, то имеет смысл подумать над структурой БД. В вашем случае таблицы *users* (уже существующие пользователи) и *invitations* (потенциальные пользователи) вполне можно объединить в одну таблицу.

Comment: на http://sqlfiddle.com  
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT `email` FROM `table1`
  UNION
  SELECT `email` FROM `table2`
) `tables`
WHERE `email` = 'email@gmail.com'  
такой запрос отлично работает, а вот в реальном проете выводит такую ошибку, я вообще не могу понять, что ему нужно, поле email одинаковое по всем параметрам и одного и того же email не может существовать в 2-х таблцах сразу.  
Текст ошибки: llegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'

Comment: Эврика, я обнаружил ошибку! Заключалась она в том, что кодировки у таблиц разные были(не понимаю каким образом они вообще там разные получились)... вообщем такой запрос работает:  
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT email FROM table1 UNION SELECT email FROM table2 ) tables WHERE email = 'email@gmail.com'
Всем спасибо!)))